# Simple Django Rest Framework Data Save

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

This should be incredibly straightforward but I'm getting strange results trying to access `serializer.data`.

I setup an exception in the `MediaViewSet` class-based view method, `perform_create`, so I can see what's going on right before it saves to database.

```
class MediaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    List, create, retrieve, update or destroy media.
    """

    queryset = Media.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MediaSerializer
    permission_classes = (UserDataAccessPermissions,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        raise Exception(serializer)
```

The results are:

```
Exception: MediaSerializer(context={'view': <main.views.MediaViewSet object>, 'format': None, 'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object>}, data=<QueryDict: {'type': ['IM'], 'media': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    media = FileField()
    type = ChoiceField(choices=(('IM', 'Image'), ('VI', 'Video')), required=False)
    thumbnail = SerializerMethodField()
```

If you scroll over, it looks as if the data argument has a proper media file saved and nothing's wrong.

---

*But*, when I change the `perform_create` method to the following, there seems to be nothing in `serializer.data`.

```
class MediaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    List, create, retrieve, update or destroy media.
    """

    queryset = Media.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MediaSerializer
    permission_classes = (UserDataAccessPermissions,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        raise Exception(serializer.data)
```

I get the following:

```
Exception: {'thumbnail': None, 'type': 'IM', 'media': None}
```

It's as if all the data has been removed and I have no idea why. Any suggestions?